# Demonstrating linear filters on daily weather data

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I have daily temperature data from some place on Earth. Apparently, the sampling frequency f_s = 1/day.

I would like to use these data to demonstrate (visually) the use of low-pass, high-pass, and maybe band-pass filters in the context of Fourier transform and convolution via multiplication. For those, one typically needs to specify the cutoff frequencies. I just can't wrap my head around it: How can one determine reasonable cutoff frequencies for such a kind of data?

Here's a plot of the "signal":
[image: Plot of the "signal"]

Comment: "reasonable" depends on "reason": What is the purpose of why you want to filter? Define that, and you'll find cutoff frequencies. Don't define it, and you can't.

Comment: Good point! As said, my personal motivation is explaining filters in a signal processing context. But I understand this is not what you mean. Maybe for the low-pass filter the reason could be that I want to determine the underlying seasonal signal, for the high-pass filter the deviations from the seasonal signal? A band-pass example probably makes no sense here.

Comment: Well a band pass could be used to determine something like medium-term averages (say, what's the biweekly average)

Answer (score 0):

A low pass filter would demonstrate long term fluctuations while removing the short term fluctuations. A high pass filter would do the opposite. The frequency cutoff as the transition between the two is the reciprocal of the duration. For example, if we chose a cutoff that is the reciprocal of 1 day (1/8640 seconds or 1.1574E-5 Hz), the output of the low pass would be useful for viewing fluctuations much longer than a day, and the output of the high pass would be useful for viewing the short term fluctuations much shorter than a day.

Similarly a bandpass could be done to view the fluctuations over a min to max time range (such as 1 day to 1 week).

The sharper the filter, the closer we can get to the boundary edges.

All results assume we have allowed for the filter outputs to settle from their initial transient responses.